# relationship of canvas scale and canvas size?

Tags: javascript, html, css, canvas

I have `240x157` png, and div size is `120x88`

So,I made canvas `240x157` and paste png.

`div` size is smaller than png but `div` has scrollbar and I can see the whole picture with dragging bar. That's perfect.

```js
var ctx = $('canvas')[0].getContext('2d');
console.log("test")

var chara = new Image();
chara.src = "https://dl.dropbox.com/s/yr8ehzbdwm0csc7/Madeira_-_Entrance_to_Town%2C_c._1900.jpg?dl=0";

chara.onload = () => { 
      ctx.clearRect(0, 0,240,157);
      ctx.drawImage(chara,0,0,240,157);

 }
```

```css
#whole{
border:1px solid;
  width:120px;
  height:78px;
  overflow:scroll;
  
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="whole">
<canvas id="test" width="240px" height="157px"></canvas>
</div>
```

My final goal is to change scale by user and when the picture is bigger than div, there appears scroll bar, like photoshop etc.

So, I test the 1/2 scale and see whole pic in `129 x78`

It looks like succeed but there still remain the scroll bar, and it scrolls no necesarry area..

Why this happens?

In my understanding when canvas size `240x157` and scale is `1/2` whole size should be appeared 120x78, why only picture shrink not canvas itself?

```js
var ctx = $('canvas')[0].getContext('2d');
console.log("test")

var chara = new Image();
chara.src = "https://dl.dropbox.com/s/yr8ehzbdwm0csc7/Madeira_-_Entrance_to_Town%2C_c._1900.jpg?dl=0";

ctx.scale(1/2,1/2) // adding here.

chara.onload = () => { 
      ctx.clearRect(0, 0,240,157);
      ctx.drawImage(chara,0,0,240,157);

 }
```

```css
#whole{
border:1px solid;
  width:120px;
  height:78px;
  overflow:scroll;
  
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="whole">
<canvas id="test" width="240px" height="157px"></canvas>
</div>
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/scale: _"The CanvasRenderingContext2D.scale() method of the Canvas 2D API adds a scaling transformation to the canvas units horizontally and/or vertically. By default, one unit on the canvas is exactly one pixel. A scaling transformation modifies this behavior. For instance, a scaling factor of 0.5 results in a unit size of 0.5 pixels; shapes are thus drawn at half the normal size."_ - this does not modify the _dimensions_ of your canvas element, only the units used to draw content onto it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to change size of the canvas and set `overflow:auto` so the scrollbars would disappear:

```js
const canvas = $('canvas')[0];

var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
console.log("test")

var chara = new Image();
chara.src = "https://dl.dropbox.com/s/yr8ehzbdwm0csc7/Madeira_-_Entrance_to_Town%2C_c._1900.jpg?dl=0";

$zoom.addEventListener('input', () =>{

  const zoom = $zoom.value * .5;

  canvas.width = 240 * zoom;
  canvas.height = 157 * zoom;

  ctx.scale(zoom,zoom) // adding here.

  ctx.clearRect(0, 0,240,157);
  ctx.drawImage(chara,0,0,240,157);


});


chara.onload = () => { 
      ctx.clearRect(0, 0,240,157);
      ctx.drawImage(chara,0,0,240,157);

 }
```

```css
#whole{
  border:1px solid;
  width:120px;
  height:78px;
  overflow:auto;
  
}
canvas{
margin:0;
display:block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="$zoom" type="range" min="1" max="10" value="2">
<div id="whole">
<canvas id="test" width="240px" height="157px"></canvas>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you verymuch , also I am confused with style sheet and width height .